# Heroku-Django South Migrations to Cloudinary Image Field

Tags: django, web-applications, heroku, django-south, cloudinary

I am developing an app which relies heavily on live user image creation upload. Since Heroku does not support live uploading (New files are flushed regularly), I am moving all images to [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/).

For models with image fields, I have added this field:

```
    c_image = CloudinaryField('image')
```

All imports work, and I made sure to add the south introspection rule:

```
add_introspection_rules([], ["^cloudinary\.models\.CloudinaryField"])
```

When I try to migrate, I get the error saying that this field is `NOT NULL` yet no default is specified.

How do I set a default value or alternatively allow for `null=true, blank=true`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CloudinaryField` is a wrapper over top of a `CharField` - you can just add `null=True, blank=True` to the field definition.

Comment: In my models.py, or in the models.py of the cloudinary folder?

Comment: Your models.py: `c_image = CloudinaryField('image', null=True, blank=True)`